# Kaa Sandbox not receiving data from Cellmonitor sample app

Tags: java, android, networking, sandbox, kaa

I just downloaded a fresh copy of Kaa sandbox and ran the cellmonitor sample app, however there is no data showing in mongo db.

I tried downloading and running directly the cellmonitor app binaries (apk), as well as building the apk from sources (by the way, a line starting the KaaManager is missing and has to be added in the MainActivity), but in neither case is working.
I made sure that the sandbox has a reachable local IP address, in the same network as the samrtphone running the app, and set that IP address in: Kaa sandbox management -> Kaa host /IP. I even tried to set as Kaa host/IP the address of the host computer it self, but still not getting any data in the DB. 
Please looking for suggestions on whta could be wrong or missing in my setup.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue already. They way to do this was simply set the network adapter of the virtual machine to bridged (not NAT), reboot and set the obtained IP address in: Kaa sandbox management -> Kaa host /IP. Regenerate the SDK (.jar file) and add it to my Android cell monitor project. Rebuild, run the app and voilá, after a couple of minutes data is reflecting in mongo DB.